# GPS Info without internet in android

Tags: java, android, gps

I want to save GPS info into database when the internet connection is off in android.
that information by which the phone detect GPS location.

is this possible?

please advice me..

Comment: *"Is this possible?"*: Everything is impossible until someone does it. Now, would you mind expanding on your question with more details so that it would be *possible* for us to answer it? Right now it's rather hard to tell what exactly you want to do and for what purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS works without Internet. Internet is only required for A-GPS (to get the position faster when GPS does not know where you are since it's way faster if GPS knows a rough area of your location).

On the other hand there is afik no way to provide that rough position to your GPS since that is not a part of Android's GPS API (GPS is really vendor specific). The implementation might already do that.

If you still want to save that location go look for Database examples - e.g. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Are you sure that a full blown Internet connection is required for A-GPS? I was under the impression that a mobile network connection was enough, even without a data link over it...

Comment: BTW, I am still not sure what the OP is asking, although your answer is sort of a catch-all :-) +1

Comment: There might be a way to do it without internet if your mobile phone provider & phone supports that (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS#Standards although I don't know for sure if those work without internet) but e.g. SUPL (which is quite commont) is using the CellID from GSM to query an Internet service (supl.google.com) that can tell you the location from that info. There is also the Wifi location thing that also requires internet to translate Wifi BSSIDs into a location.